# Install Adblock on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, safari

I have an iPad 3 with iOS 8.3; I wonder if there is some software/tool that allows  to install Adblock and how to enable it on Safari (if I can of course).

Comment: I use something called [Adguard Pro](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/adguard-pro-adblock-and-privacy-protection/id1126386264?mt=8) on my iPhone/iPad. It requires a minimum of iOS 9, though, which your iPad 3 can run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are apps which aren't content blockers, but which rather install a VPN on your device and route your traffic through this to block ads. This is still supported on devices which don't support content blockers.

- [image] [AdBlock](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/adblock/id691121579?mt=8&at=1001lwpF)
- [[image] AdGuard](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/adguard-pro-adblock-and-privacy-protection/id1126386264?mt=8&at=1001lwpF)

---

For other devices which do support [content blockers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ContentBlocker.html) on iOS 9, there are many options available.

- [[image] Crystal](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/crystal-adblock-block-unwanted-ads/id1022177308?mt=8&at=1001lwpF)
- [[image] AdBlock Plus](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/adblock-plus-abp-remove-ads-browse-faster-without-tracking/id1028871868?mt=8)
- [[image] Aqua](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/aqua-ad-blocker-block-ads-in-web-and-apps/id1227177591?mt=8&at=1001lwpF)
- [[image] AdBlock for Mobile](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/adblock-for-mobile/id1036484810?mt=8&at=1001lwpF)

To add a content blocker, install it from the App Store, then choose Settings → Safari → Content Blockers and enable the content blocker. For apps which do not use content blockers, see the app itself for installation instructions.

Comment: Safari content blockers require a device with a 64-bit SoC, of which the iPad 3 isn’t. So fake-VPN apps, and third-party browsers with built-in ad-blockers seem like the only solutions.

Comment: @Phong Thanks, edited my answer, I should have remembered this since I have an iPad 2 with iOS 9 but no content blockers!